# how to find date and ipaddress in a text with regex in unix bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I have to find out the date and ipaddresses in a text file by regex in Unix bash. Below is my script, but it does not able to parse

```
#!/bin/bash
# script to parse Record1.txt such that tokenize with coma, that find, date with#time, ipaddress,url in this.
OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$','
arr=($(sed 's_{,}_\s_g' Record1.txt ))
IFS="$OIFS"
pattern_date=""
pattern_ipaddress=""
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
        pattern_date=$(echo $i|grep '\d{4}[-/]\d{2}[-/]\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}')
        pattern_ipaddress=$(echo $i|grep '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}')
        echo "pattern_date =$pattern_date"
        echo "pattern_ipaddress=$pattern_ipaddress"
        if [  $i = '$pattern_date'  ]
        then
                echo $i
        elif [ $i = '$pattern_ipaddress' ]
        then
                echo $i
        fi
#check for ipaddress: ipaddress patern will be \d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3} 




done
```

The data sample is as below

```
2014/08/06 05:15:00,00.28.185.69,170188,13609FAD,tsp08.sprintpcs.com,0123456789,Framed-User,10.152.181.33,000007632306609,102400,102400,300,Unknown,2014/08/06 05:15:00,,2014/08/06 05:10:00,2014/08/06 05:15:00,0123456789,120E00644D93,Stop,Mobile,1xRSS~#~pdc001.abc.net
```

Could any body tell me where is hte issues

Comment: Please provide a minimal example including your desired output.

Comment: Is your output following some kind of formatting rule? Like a CSV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should use Perl regexp.

```
grep -P '\d{4}[-/]\d{2}[-/]\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use sed instead of those cycles 
`sed 's|^\([^ ]*\) \([^,]*,\)\{7\}\([^,]*\),.*|\1 \3|' Record1.txt`

Comment: it doesn't work. I put this statement just from of grep, but now output comes

Comment: Sorry, i did not understood your comment. grep have nothing to do with this statement. Just feed your data to this sed command and you will get "date ip" strings on output. The actual example I have tested on is `echo '2014/08/06 05:15:00,00.28.185.69,170188,13609FAD,tsp08.sprintpcs.com,0123456789,Framed-User,10.152.181.33,000007632306609,102400,102400,300,Unknown,2014/08/06 05:15:00,,2014/08/06 05:10:00,2014/08/06 05:15:00,0123456789,120E00644D93,Stop,Mobile,1xRSS~#~pdc001.abc.net' | sed 's|^\([^ ]*\) \([^,]*,\)\{7\}\([^,]*\),.*|\1 \3|'`

Answer (score 0):

Using `cut` might help

```
data="2014/08/06 05:15:00,00.28.185.69,170188,13609FAD,tsp08.sprintpcs.com,0123456789,Framed-User,10.152.181.33,000007632306609,102400,102400,300,Unknown,2014/08/06 05:15:00,,2014/08/06 05:10:00,2014/08/06 05:15:00,0123456789,120E00644D93,Stop,Mobile,1xRSS~#~pdc001.abc.net"
echo "$data" | cut -d ',' -f1,8
2014/08/06 05:15:00,10.152.181.33
```

Then you can extract the address with

```
reduce="$(echo "$data" | cut -d ',' -f1,8 )"
mydate="$(echo "$reduce" | cut -d ' ' -f1 )"
myip="$(echo "$reduce" | cut -d ',' -f2 )"
```